# AngularJS dropdownlist first value is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I have a dropdown list and I'm using AngularJS as the frontend framework. However the first value in dropdownlist is always empty. Can anyone explain to me what happened? where I need to change? Thanks!

here is the html

```
 <div class="input-control select" ng-controller="democtrl">
            <select ng-model="selectedOption">
                <option selected>Select the option</option>
                <option value="ip">IP</option>
                <option value="host">Host</option>
            </select>
            {{selectedOption}}
        </div>
```

here is the js code:

```
 angular.module('demo')
      .controller('democtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.selectedOption = "test";

      }]);
```

Comment: your angular module definition does not have dependencies defined. Try changing it to angular.module('demo',[]). You can find the plunk here https://embed.plnkr.co/9SdR02Hro7ORz7zf20Ea/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you don't have any html option with value `test` but you are setting the model to this value.

Try either leaving `selectedOption` empty or setting it to the an existing value:

```
angular.module('demo')
      .controller('democtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.selectedOption = "ip";
      }]);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This does help! It saves my time! ;-)

Comment: @catlovespurple Glad it does. Please mark as correct answer.